# Option 2 is running the code meant for another if statement

Tags: c++

Whenever I run the second choice it doesn't run the code I mean for it and I don't know why. It will run what will happen if you chose option 2.

```c++
do
{
    getline(cin, cont)

    cout << "1 hour has passed. There is " << (dist1 = dist1 - 3) << "km left" << endl;
    ran = rand() % 7;
    if (ran == 1)
    {
        troll(trollh);
        cout << "Option 1: Fight" << endl;
        cout << "Option 2: Run" << endl;
        ask(choice);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            damageony = (rand() % 2) + 2;
            shealth = hhealth(damageony, shealth);
            damage = (rand() % 5) + slevel;
            whhealth(damage, trollh);

            cout << "You are fighting and this is what happened" << endl;
            cout << "You have " << shealth << "health left" << endl;
            cout << "You did " << damage << "damage to the troll" << endl;
            xpch(xp, damageony);
            stats(shealth, slevel, xp, scoins);
            ddeath(shealth);
            do
            {
                if (trollh >= 1)
                {
                    damageony = (rand() % 2) + 1;
                    shealth = hhealth(damageony, shealth);
                    damage = (rand() % 5) + slevel;
                    whhealth(damage, trollh);

                    cout << "You are fighting and this is what happened" << endl;
                    cout << "You have " << shealth << "health left" << endl;
                    cout << "You did " << damage << "damage to the troll" << endl;
                    xpch(xp, damageony);
                    stats(shealth, slevel, xp, scoins);
                    ddeath(shealth);
                }
            } while (trollh >= 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "You chose to run away and now there is " << (dist1 = dist1 + 1) << "km left" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (dist1 >= 41);
```

Comment: Look up the `switch` statement.  IMHO, much clearer to read with integer variables than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Evil code.  Assignment statement in a `cout` statement.

Comment: Please show us your `ask` function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ask takes a reference parameter and also that choice is an int and not a character. This is because char 1 is not the same thing as int 1. Chars get casted into the integer value of their ASCII code.

Comment: This would make for a good comment, but there's too much unknown for this to make an answer.